# How I can introduce a node with Unique key, in my values using a Hashmap? Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```html
 public void createArtist()//View view ES PARA HACER FUNCIONAR EN ONCLICK EN XML
    {
        final String giro = spingiro.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String sexo = spinsexo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String pais = spinpais.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String estado = spinestado.getSelectedItem().toString();
        final String ciudad = spinciudad.getSelectedItem().toString();

        HashMap<String, String> Personal = new HashMap<>();
        Personal.put("id", databaseReference.push().getKey());
        Personal.put("correo", edtRegCorreoSocio.getText().toString());
        Personal.put("contraseña",edtRegContraSocio.getText().toString());

        Socios socios = new Socios(databaseReference.push().getKey(), edtRegCorreoSocio.getText().toString(),
                edtRegContraSocio.getText().toString(), edtRegNombreCompleto.getText().toString(),
                edtRegNombreNegocio.getText().toString(), giro,
                edtRegAntiguedad.getText().toString(), edtRegRfc.getText().toString(), edtRegMovil.getText().toString(), sexo, ciudad, Personal);

        databaseReference.child("Socios").child(giro).child(socios.getId()).setValue(socios);

        //PARA LIMPIAR EL EDITTEXT DESPUES DE DAR CLICK AL BOTON
        edtRegContraSocio.getText().clear();
        edtRegCorreoSocio.getText().clear();
        edtRegNombreCompleto.getText().clear();
        edtRegAntiguedad.getText().clear();
        edtRegRfc.getText().clear();
        edtRegMovil.getText().clear();
        edtRegNombreNegocio.getText().clear();
    }
```

Good morning!! I'll being trying 4 days and I just can´t do it!!
How I can put a node with unique Key in my values using Firebase and Android Studio.
I just add what I need to do with screenshots!

[Here is my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lSA.png)

[Here is my POJO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1porr.png)

[And here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE01m.png)

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as a picture.

Comment: Same applies for the JSON: add it as text, not as an image. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Like that?
But how I can generate the Key of each "Personal"? inside the values of "Socio/Estetica" ?

Comment: Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii???

Comment: @GilbertoDuranBringas you can use `push()` method to generate unique key, that's all I can tell you. If you would clear the question a bit more, I may be able to help more.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit please look my DB image, there is what I want to do exactly, please man!

Comment: Yes for that all you need to do is, use `push()` method before setting those values which you want to set under `personal` node. Read more about that here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjIuvOhye7eAhUFyqQKHagZCZYQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fdatabase%2Fandroid%2Fread-and-write&usg=AOvVaw2WDmuUsyGannfSDbRR18Wm